# How can I add count for the search results into the codemirror

Tags: angular, typescript, codemirror

After I did some search about how to add the count of search results to codemirror like the picture, I didn't find anything, I'm working on angular and I used ngx-codemirror, so I found that the only way is to edit the search.js in the package of ngx-codemirror.

I need to search for a better way because if I would change the search.js file in the package it will be a little bad because we are working on a team and everyday there are so many pushes and we can't push the node_modules every time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Solution for angular :

**Note** : Keep in mind this is not the best solution
(without editing `CodeMirror` package)

### HTML :

```html
        <ngx-codemirror #codeEditor [(ngModel)]="htmlString" [options]="options" name="html">
        </ngx-codemirror>
        <span *ngIf="resultCount > 0" class="btn"> Search amount : {{ resultCount }}</span>
```

### Typescript :

```js
        export class HtmlEditorComponent
          implements OnInit, DoCheck {

          @ViewChild('codeEditor') codeEditor: CodemirrorComponent;
          resultCount = 0;
          htmlString = '';

          constructor() {}

          ngDoCheck() {
            if (
              this.codeEditor &&
              this.codeEditor.codeMirror &&
              this.htmlString.length > 0
            ) {
              this.checkSearch();
            }
          }

          checkSearch() {
            const searchField = document.getElementsByClassName(
              'CodeMirror-search-field'
            )[0] as any;
            if (searchField && searchField.value.length > 0) {
              const text = new RegExp(searchField.value, 'gi');
              const count = (this.htmlString.match(text) || []).length;
              this.resultCount = count;
            } else {
              this.resultCount = 0;
            }
          }
        }
```

Try now with CTRL+F on `CodeMirror` and you will see the search count

Live Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-codemirror-search-count